# $C[0,1]$ is separable: Theorem $11.2$ Carothers' Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation, separable-spaces

I have some questions about the proof of Theorem 11.2 of Carothers' Real Analysis. The theorem states that $C[0,1]$ is separable.

---

1. Why is $\|f-g\|_\infty \le\epsilon$?
2. Why is $h$ selected the way it is, i.e. $h(k/n) = f(k/n)$ for $k = 0,1,2...,n$ but with $h(k/n)$ rational and satisfying $|h(k/n) - g(k/n)| < \epsilon$? I think the reason we can do this is because $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, but I don't understand the motivation.
3. How do we get $\|g-h\|_\infty < \epsilon$? Is the proof similar to (1)?
4. The proof is concluded with: "The set of all polygonal functions taking only rational values at nodes $(k/n)_{k=0}^n$ for some $n$ is countable." Well, why is that - and how does this show that $C[0,1]$ is separable?

To show that $C[0,1]$ is separable, I would expect a countable **dense** subset of $C[0,1]$. Where is this set?

> [image]

In case someone is curious as to what Exercise $1$ is, I'm typing it below:

> For each $n$, let $Q_n$ be the set of all polygonal functions that have nodes at $x = k/n$, $k = 0,1,...,n$ and that take on only rational values at these points. Check that $Q_n$ is a countable set and hence that the union of the $Q_n$'s is a countable dense set in $C[0,1]$.

Comment: Your first question makes no sense. If it was simply “Why is $\|f-g\|_\infty\leqslant\varepsilon$?”, it would would be fine. But it is followed by “Does this hold only if $|x-y|<1/n$ or in general?” Since there is no $x$, no $y$, and no $n$ in the first question, what can this possibly mean?

Comment: First you approximate $f$ with $g$, then you approximate $g$ with $h$, with both approximations being uniform. Thus, in some sense we have a transitive property - if $h$ approximates $g$ uniformly and $g$ approximates $f$ uniformly, then in fact, $h$ approximates $f$ uniformly. We can approximate $g$ by $h$ because as you said - rationals are dense in the reals. The approximation can be made uniform as well, because 1. we do so at only finitely many points, 2. the interpolation between the points is linear for both $g,h$.

Comment: For question 1: note that if $k/n \leq x \leq (k + 1)/n$, then we must have
$$
f(k/n) \leq g(x) \leq f((k+1)/n) \quad \text{ OR} \quad f((k+1)/n) \leq g(x)\leq f(k/n).
$$
Compare $|g(x) - f(x)|$ to $|f(k/n) - f(x)|$ and $|f((k+1)/n) - f(x)|$.

Comment: How should I make that comparison? Could you say a little more? @BenGrossmann

Comment: @epsilon-emperor Use the inequalities involving $g(x)$ to get inequalities involving $g(x) - f(x)$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I did that. Suppose $f(k/n) \le g(x) \le f((k+1)/n)$, then $g(x) - f(x) \le f((k+1)/n) - f(x)$. We have $|f((k+1)/n) - f(x)| < \epsilon$, which means $f((k+1)/n) - f(x) < \epsilon$. This gives $g(x) - f(x) < \epsilon$. If $g(x) \ge f(x)$, then $|g(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$. However, if $g(x) < f(x)$, what do we do (we can't just take the absolute value on both sides of the inequality)?

Comment: @epsilon-emperor If three real numbers $a,b,c$ satisfy $a \leq b \leq c$, then it must hold either that $|b| \leq |a|$ or $|b| \leq |c|$. That is, it is always the case that $|b| \leq \max\{|a|,|c|\}$. In this case, take 
$$
a = f(k/n) - f(x), \quad b = g(x) - f(x), \quad c = f((k+1)/n) - f(x)
$$
or switch $a$ and $c$ if necessary.

Comment: Yup, I realized that after a bit. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) You get $\| f - g\|_\infty \le \epsilon$ by simply taking more and more points (i.e., increasing $n$). Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, if $g$ matches $f$ at every point $k/n$ and $n$ is large enough, you will eventually get $\lvert f(x) - g(x) \rvert \le \epsilon$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ because $$\lvert f(x) - g(x) \rvert \le \underbrace{\lvert f(x) - f(k/n)\rvert}_{\text{small by continuity of } f} + \underbrace{\lvert f(k/n) - g(k/n) \rvert}_{=0, \text{ by def. of } g} + \underbrace{\lvert g(k/n) - g(x) \rvert}_{\text{small by continuity of } g}$$ where you choose the $k/n$ closest to $x$ in the above line.

(2) You can't have $h(k/n)= f(k/n)$ because you need the values of $h(k/n)$ to be rational (to ensure the family of such $h$ remains countable) but you may have $f(k/n)$ irrational. So you first make the $g$ with $g(k/n) = f(k/n)$; $g$ is a nice polygonal function, but may have irrational values at nodes $k/n$. However, because of density of the rationals, there is a rational point as close as desired to $g(k/n)$. Define $h$ the same way as $g$ but with $h(k/n)$ a rational number such that $\lvert h(k/n) - g(k/n) \rvert \le \epsilon$. Then $h$ pretty well approximates $g$ and $g$ pretty well approximates $f$ so $h$ pretty well approximates $f$, and has rational values at nodes $k/n$.

(3) Density of the rationals: you're just taking $g$ and possibly moving its values as nodes $k/n$ by a tiny bit.

(4) The countable dense set is the set of polygonal functions $h$ such that $h(k/n)$ is rational for all $k = 0,1,\ldots,n$. This set is countable because it can be seen as a subset of $$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} \mathbb Q^{n+1}$$ via the following reasoning: choose the number $n$ of nodes, then choose the $n+1$ rational values at nodes $k/n$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,n$, and you have uniquely determined your polygonal function $h$. But $\mathbb Q^{n+1}$ is countable, and a countable union of countable sets is countable, so this shows that the set of such functions $h$ is countable.

Comment: Your first answer doesn't quite address the question being asked. Yes, you have validly argued that there exists **some** sufficiently large $n$ to ensure that $\|f - g\|_\infty < \epsilon$. However, you did not show that the $n$ described in the proof is sufficiently large.

Comment: Could you elaborate on (1), please? When you say *small* - **how small** do you mean? Could you quantify that in terms of $\epsilon$ perhaps? We choose the $k/n$ closest to the $x$ in consideration. So, we must have $|x - k/n| < 1/n$ (since the distance between successive nodes is $1/n$). Hence, $|f(x) - f(k/n) | < \epsilon$. Now what about $|g(x) - g(k/n)| = |g(x) - f(k/n)|$?

Comment: (4) - why is this set dense? Countability seems fine.

Comment: @epsilon-emperor A subset $D \subset X$ (where $X$ is a metric space) is dense iff for any $\epsilon > 0$ and any member $x \in X$, there is a member $y \in D$ such that $d(x,y) < \epsilon$. Here the metric space is $C[0,1]$, the subset is the collection of all such $h$. Ensuring you can find some $h$ within $\epsilon$ of $f$ proves density.

Comment: **Small** means as small as desired. By uniform continuity of $f$ for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert x - y \rvert < \delta \implies \lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert < \epsilon$. Use $\epsilon / 2$ rather than $\epsilon$ and take $n$ large enough that $1/n < \delta$ and then $\lvert x - k/n\vert < \frac 1 n < \delta$, so we conclude that $\lvert f(x) - f(k/n) \rvert < \epsilon/2$. Now do the same for $g$, and take the larger of the two $n$ values.

Comment: @User8128 Thank you, I understand it now. I propose a *small* change to (1). Let's find $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ such that for every $x,y$: $$|x- y| < \delta_1 \implies |f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon/2\\ |x- y| < \delta_2 \implies |g(x)-g(y)| < \epsilon/2$$
Then, choose $n$ large enough so that $$1/n < \min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$$
Sounds good, right?

Comment: About $\|g-h\|_\infty < \epsilon$, here are my thoughts. Please let me know if the proof sounds OK. $$|g(x) - h(x)| \le |g(x) - g(k/n)| + |g(k/n) - h(k/n)| + |h(k/n) - h(x)|$$
By uniform continuity of $g$ and $h$, $$|x- y| < \delta_1 \implies |g(x)-g(y)| < \epsilon/3\\ |x- y| < \delta_2 \implies |h(x)-h(y)| < \epsilon/3$$
Then, choose $n$ s.t. $1/n < \min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$
We **construct** $h$ so that $h(k/n)$ is rational and $|g(k/n) - h(k/n)| < \epsilon/3$ (due to density of $\mathbb Q$). So, $|g(x) - h(x)| < 3\cdot \epsilon/3 = \epsilon$. @User8128